# Exceptional regex for email id validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

What could be the Regex for accepting `.@.` as a valid email id? Also need to check the below conditions.

1. Should contain exactly one `@` character.
2. Before and after `@` should consist of at least 1 and at most 64 characters comprising only letters, digits and/or dots`(a-z, A-Z, 0-9, .)`.

was trying with `\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{0,0}` but not working as expected.

Comment: `/[a-z0-9.]{1,64}@[a-z0-9.]{1,64}/i` should do the trick (inside `[]` brackets, `.` does not need to be escaped, it's a litteral character) [Regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/11jW1i/1/)

Comment: It's a waste of time, check the arobase, eventually a minimal length, but send an email with a confirmation link.

Comment: @blex Can you post this as an answer? so that I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/^[a-z0-9.]{1,64}@[a-z0-9.]{1,64}$/i` should do the trick ([Regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/PeJ142/1/)):

```js
function demo(str) {
  const isEmail = /^[a-z0-9.]{1,64}@[a-z0-9.]{1,64}$/i.test(str);
  console.log(isEmail, str);
}

demo('.@.'); // OK
demo('abc.123@abc.123'); // OK
demo('a-b_c@a_b'); // Bad chars
demo('a.b.c'); // No @
demo('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234@a'); // OK
demo('12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345@a'); // Too long
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should contain exactly one @ character.
> 2. Before and after @ should consist of at least 1 and at most 64 characters comprising only letters, digits and/or dots(a-z, A-Z, 0-9, .).

You don't need regex for that:

```js
const validateEmail = (email) => {
  const parts = email.split('@');
  if (parts.length !== 2) {
    // Either no @ or more than one
    return false;
  }
  const [before, after] = parts;
  return (
    before.length > 0 && 
    before.length <= 64
  ) && (
    after.length > 0 && 
    after.length <= 64
  );
}

console.log(
  validateEmail('.@.'),
  validateEmail('some.mail@this.thing'),
  validateEmail('wrong@'),
  validateEmail('this@is@wrong'),
);
```

Using regex would be overkill, and will likely be a lot slower than performing 1 split, and 3 equality checks.

Comment: This is not checking the character limit

Comment: This makes `"$@$"` valid

Comment: And it is 11% to 15% slower than using Regex in Chrome & Firefox ([JSBench](https://jsbench.me/zzkobt8m9k/1)). Way overkill, keep it simple with regex